# How could a large owner of Bitcoin give back to the Bitcoin community in an equal way?

Tags: economic-theory

If there was one large owner of Bitcoin, for example somebody who owned 3% of all mined Bitcoins, would there be a way for that person to give back their Bitcoins in an equal way? I'm thinking more along the lines of equally giving their money away to other Bitcoin holders based on how much money they had invested in the currency, not really along the lines of using their wealth to lobby companies to accept Bitcoin.

Answer (score 4):

By destroying his coins ( sending them to an address noone has the private key for, like 1nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn )

Comment: So you just make them more scarce? That's a pretty clever solution, instead of sending `1/N` of your total amount to `N` used addresses.

Answer (score 0):

An airdrop-style event in the vein of AuroraCoin would allow for an equitable distribution.  Those with less bitcoin would also be more likely to go through the process of verifying themselves to claim the funds. (infographic explanation of 'airdrop' process here
http://auroracoin.com/)

While proof of burn is an imaginative solution, the practical effects would not be as immediately tangible to most folks, even though the theoretical effects are sound.  Because so many bitcoins are hoarded anyway (*cough* *cough* satoshi *cough*), the destruction of some coins would go largely unnoticed unless the amount was tremendous.

Answer (score 0):

An idea would be to sponsor open source project that help the open source community and their infrastructure. In this case, they could help Bitcoin related open source projects that help the Bitcoin infrastructure.